# Log4j in file Spark

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

I am trying to log my project. For that, I'm using log4j and I'm putting the information and settings in the code itself, without using the properties file, as shown below.

```java
public class Teste {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Teste.class.getName());

    public static void configError() {

        EnhancedPatternLayout layout = new EnhancedPatternLayout();
        String conversionPattern = "%d{ISO8601}{GMT+1} %-5p %m%n";
        layout.setConversionPattern(conversionPattern);
        String fileError = "C:/ProducerError.log";

        // creates console appender
        ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender();
        consoleAppender.setLayout(layout);
        consoleAppender.activateOptions();

        // creates file appender
        FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender();
        fileAppender.setFile(fileError);
        fileAppender.setLayout(layout);
        fileAppender.activateOptions();

        // configures the root logger
        Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
        rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        rootLogger.addAppender(consoleAppender);
        rootLogger.addAppender(fileAppender);

        log.error("Error teste");

        rootLogger.removeAllAppenders();
    }
}
```

I wanted to do the same but in a spark file. I tried the same way but it doesn't return anything. How does spark logs work? Can't I put it in the code like I did before? I have a DockerFile with spark-submit, but I didn't want to mess with that code.

Answer (score 0):

Provide config file path while submitting the spark job `-Dlog4j.configuration=path/to/log4j.properties`

Comment: And should I provide this path in my spark code? At the beginning of the code put this and then, in the parts of the code that interest me, do I put log.info("Test")? I wanted to put logs in my code but I don't know how it works in spark, if it is the same as in java.

Comment: If you want to put log in your code, it is same as in java. The above config will tell spark that it should use this config for logging from spark and dependent libraries

Comment: So the idea is to put the logs in the code, in the parts that interest me. Since spark-submit already calls this function, there is no need for anything regarding the log

Comment: Can I put the log in an RDD trench? I have an expression rdd.foreachPartitionAsync and the log did not print here